# Regular Expression for 3:00pm to 4:20

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regular expression for find particular pattern like .

String : **In meeting 3:00pm to 4:20 at Ahmedabad**.

From that String i need only **3:00pm to 4:20**.

and expression :

```
var time_range = message.match**(/(\w+)\s(to)\s(\w+)/gi)**
```

but this expression have some limitations.

1. In meeting 3pm to 6pm at Ahmedabad (its work fine) but
2. In meeting 3:40pm to 6:30pm at Ahmedabad(than there is problem because of **(:)**)

Comment: Your regex will also match `rags to riches`, i.e. any words. Is it a problem?

Comment: yes, but i have another regular expression for match these patterns.

Answer (score 2):

This regex would work for most cases and it won't check for the proper time.

```
\b(\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?(?:[ap]m))\s(to)\s(\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?(?:[ap]m))\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/47)

For simple case, just put `:` and `\w` inside a character class and makes it to repeat one or more times by adding `+` quantifier next to that character class.

```
([:\w]+)\s(to)\s([:\w]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/48)

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(?::\d+)?\s*(?:[ap]m)?\s*to\s*\d+(?::\d+)?\s*(?:[ap]m)?
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/49

```
var re = /\d+(?::\d+)?\s*(?:[ap]m)?\s*to\s*\d+(?::\d+)?\s*(?:[ap]m)?/gm;
var str = 'In meeting 3:00pm to 4:20 at Ahmedabad.\nIn meeting 3pm to 6pm at Ahmedabad\nIn meeting 3:00pm to 4:20am at Ahmedabad.';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```